# Is this valid to use a resource in exe found by signature scanning?

Tags: winapi, file, resources

I suppose there's no way to use resource from exe without full loading it into memory. Let's say I have plans to use large RC_DATA resource I prepared myself. Is it ok to find it inside my executable by signature scanning and use it with CreateFile and offset after that?

Thanks

Comment: The assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but you don't load the entire exe into memory when you try to access it. All you need to do is:

```
HRSRC hres = FindResource(NULL, // Returns the current process as a resource
                          "Name",
                          RT_RCDATA);
```

And then just load it:

```
HGLOBAL hglob = LoadResource(NULL,
                             hres);
```

And this will give you the pointer to the first byte:

```
LPVOID lpFirstByte = LockResource(hglob);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it seems I tried to make things more complex than they are. Looks like the whole exe is already memory-mapped and it just returns the corresponding offset for a resource without even loading it into separated memory. The name of the function LoadResource is misleading probably due to the fact that in Windows 3.1 it was really "loading"